# This is my connection string please tell me what is the problem

Tags: c#

I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'provider'

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="Key_MvcDataEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model_MvcCommon.csdl|res://*/Model_MvcCommon.ssdl|res://*/Model_MvcCommon.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-9P259VD;initial catalog=Key_IndigoSeaWays;persist security info=True;User Id=sa;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Please post your connection string

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this connection string, are you sure that this one is actually used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace `&quot;` with single quotes and try again.